# How to find a vector in a 2D vectors in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I'm trying to implement a function to find a vector in a 2D vector. What i have wrote is:

```
vector<vector<int> > result;
vector<int> line;
bool isPresent = find(result.begin(), result.end(), line)
```

However, this gives an error that

"Line 11: cannot convert ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator*, std::vector > >’ to ‘bool’ in initialization"

I searched many forums but couldn't find the right answer. What is the best way to do that?

Thanks,
Shawn

Comment: `find` returns an iterator not a boolean value.

Comment: You "searched many forums" but didn't simply consult the nearest available standard library reference? The first ones on Google provide examples of just this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`InputIterator std::find(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& val)`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find)

> Returns an **iterator** to the first element in the range [first,last) that compares equal to val. If no such element is found, the function returns last.

Instead use:

```
bool isPresent = std::find(result.begin(), result.end(), line) != result.end();
//                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

or:

```
bool isPresent = std::any_of(result.begin(), result.end(),
                             [&line](const std::vector<int>& x)
                             { return x == line; });
```

Answer (score 3):

Change by:

`bool isPresent = (find(result.begin(), result.end(), line) != result.end());`

Or Better if C++11 allowed:

`bool isPresent = (find(cbegin(result), cend(result), line) != cend(result));`

The method [`std::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) of the containers return an `iterator` of the element that match or the `range end` (*last* in the signature method) provided if the element is not present.

```
template <class InputIterator, class T>
InputIterator find (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& val);
```

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be `find` returns the iterator where it found the item you asked it to find and not a boolean.

It should look like this:

```
vector<vector<int> > result;
vector<int> line;
vector< vector<int> >::iterator it = find(result.begin(), result.end(), line);
bool isPresent = ( it != result.end() );
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to

```
bool isPresent = find(result.begin(), result.end(), line) != result.end();
```

That should work as you want it. As mentioned [`std::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) returns a `vector<vector<int> >::iterator`, not a `bool`.